# Сервису получить данные

Tags: android, service

Как сервису получить данные при старте, например есть активити приложения, по нему переход в активити настроек. там набор параметров как пример  логин или чек бокс стоит или не стоит. Из активити параметров легко передать в сервис бинд или ресивер,  если служба стартует в автозагрузке то приложение не стартовало. Как сервису получить параметры из настроек активити. Подскажите кто знает? В настройках ативити сохраняю через шарепреференс но как данные получить в сервис при автозагрузке?

**Обновление**

Ну я так и пытаюсь через шаредпереференс вроде как он сохраняет в файле, а при загрузке прогружает ранее введенное в поле или проверка чек бокс. Если я в сервисе пишу код лоад шаредпреференс, то есть загрузить в сервисе поле введенное в настройках активити, то в лог идет в место имя пользователя `[ 08-12 20:19:22.483 18925:0x49ed D/MyLogs   ]` вот что пишет. Я так понимаю, что это из за приватмод. По идее приватмод доступно приложению, то есть и сервису и другим активити в этом приложении. Или это не верно?

Comment: Попробуйте формальнее описать, что вы имеете и что хотите получить в итоге. Сейчас сложно вычленить из вашего сообщения нужную информацию.

Comment: Может так же - из шаредпреференс?

Comment: Да получилось из шаредпреференс надо использовать гетшаредпреференс и не гетпреференс (для текущего активити как я понял

Answer (score 1):

решил все через шаредпреференс. активити сохраняет в файл а сервис берет из файла.

Comment: Мне кажется, этой информации недостаточно для того, чтобы будущие читатели могли использовать это решение. Не могли бы вы дать более подробные инструкции?

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, нужно пересмотреть зависимости Ваших компонентов.
Сервис должен сам хранить настройки, раз он стартует первым и они ему нужны.
А активити должна читать и менять их через методы сервиса.
Тогда все будет в одном месте и корректно работать.

Comment: Да спасибо, за совет. Пока решил все через шаредпреференс.